# Netbenas X-Debug socket exception

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, configuration, xdebug

I'am trying to debug my php files via x-debug and Netbeans
I'am using

Netbeans 8.0,
PHP version  5.5.11,
Xampp 1.8.3,
xdebug:2.2.5(latest version when i check it from wizard),
OS:Windows 7

xdebug php.ini configuration

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

With this system and configuration when i try to debug my php file i'am getting `socket exception` on Netbeans 8.0. I have read and tried almost all solutions on web but couldn't fix it.

What can be the reason of this problem ? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: can you try it with one of the following files [xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-nts](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-nts.dll) and [xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-TS](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll)

Comment: @moskito-x it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-nts.dll needs

`MSVCR110.DLL` I'm not sure if this file is located on your computer

and look for `Php5.dll` and put `php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-nts.dll` into the same folder.

Mostly in the `C:\xampp\php\` folder not `C:\xampp\php\ext\`

Comment: Do i need put the `php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-nts.dll` file to C:\xampp\php\ext\ ? Because it is defaultly placed on there.

Comment: @Tartar : It should be in the folder where Php5.dll is.